# Alternative to DFS-R on Amazon EC2 Windows Servers

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, amazon-ec2, dfs-r

For hosting our web sites in a Windows load-balanced environment we've traditionally used DFSR to sync folders between servers with our hosting company.

We're looking to migrate a lot of our sites to Amazon EC2 and I'm playing around with load balanced setups at the moment.  That's all going fine, but now I'm onto trying to get folders/drives to sync between web servers.

Ideally I'd like to use DFSR, but it relies on having a domain controller in order to sync folders.  After some research into setting up a DC on EC2 it appears that this is quite tricky (and somewhat outside my area of expertise as a developer) but I've seen it said once or twice that it's not necessarily that reliable?

So far alternatives I've looked into:

- Network share from www1 to www2 - if this is on a single web server then it provides a single point of failure (plus we've had performance issues with this).
- Network share on a separate "micro" Windows instance - again, provides a single point of failure as if this instance goes down then the whole site
- Cached network drive - I investigated using a cached network drive to get around the "single point of failure" issue, however, it's tricky to get a persistent networked drive that IIS will be able to see, and even then, I couldn't see a way to cache it (plus I'm not sure how quickly changes would be replicated between machines).
- Robocopy - from what I've seen this this could be useful if I ran it every minute, but it looks like it won't copy locked files?  Also, there would be a lag in sync-times

Sorry if that's not explained very well or I've missed something obvious.  Has anyone come up with a good, reliable method of syncing folders between web servers on Amazon EC2 which is as good as DFSR (or close)?

Comment: windows 2012 has the ability to support file server scale out, I'm just not sure if amazon support this process and if its economical.

Comment: Amazon says that 2012 pricing is the same as any other version of windows, and that you can create a Storage Space on EBS volumes. So, this could easily be the winner.

Comment: Interesting - I'll take a look at that today - thanks guys :)

Comment: How often do your files really change?

Comment: @dusan.bajic, it depends on the client and website, we generally need it for CMS sites where the client will be regularly uploading content and assets.

Comment: @mfinni - I've been reading up on storage spaces and I can't see a solid example of using Storage Spaces to mirror content across two servers. In fact, I saw it said that SS *aren't* a replication solution - do you have an example of using it to replicate content across two servers?

Comment: Nope, I was riffing on tony's comment. Without a domain, you can't do DFSR, AFAICT. And if storage spaces don't do replication, then that's not an alternative. The proper answer is to use highly-available shared storage if out-of-sync copies will ever be a problem. DFSR would present the same problem; it's not instantaneous, and it doesn't handle multiple-server locking.

Comment: why is setting up a dc in ec2 so difficult?

Comment: also I was not thinking of storage spaces, just guest level clustering via smb3.

Comment: @mfinni - we've been using DFSR for years and it's met our needs without any issue - it's always been pretty much instantaneous even when releasing large amounts of files it syncs within seconds.

Comment: @tonyroth I'm not a server admin and I have no experience in setting up DC. All the guides I've seen online indicate that I'd need to spin up at least 2 more servers and that, ideally start using a VPC in order to get private static IPs. This presents two problems 1) cost; we're using EC2 primarily to reduce cost, so having to spin up extra servers just as DCs 2) my complete lack of experience in this area would be a cause for concern should something go wrong and cause outages for our clients.  If you know of a good guide that shows how to set up a DC simply in the cloud that would be awesome

Comment: @tonyroth That's not what a Scale Out File Server is or how it works.

Comment: Check out cloudberry lab's s3 sync software called cloudberry box

Answer (score 1):

Use [S3](http://aws.amazon.com/s3/) for user generated content (one bucket that all webservers will have access to), and keep application on EC2 webservers?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but we are moving existing applications onto EC2, some of which would require a fair amount of dev to integrate with S3.  Do you know of a reliable way of mapping S3 to a drive on Windows server?  I'd be looking for something that works like Dropbox but for S3 (i.e. content is stored locally, but synced between S3 as it changes locally/on S3)

Comment: You can find some third party tools recommendations on AWS forums but I believe none of them is officially supported by Amazon. I've successfully used s3.exe from http://s3.codeplex.com/ to sync windows folder with s3 bucket but not for real-time sync.